# NSView with a KVC property in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, kvc

I have a custom NSView class defined as:

```
class MyView: NSView
{
    var someText: NSString

    override func didChangeValueForKey(key: String)
    {
        println( key )

        super.didChangeValueForKey( key )
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

What I want to be able to do is from outside of this class change the value of someText and have didChangeValueForKey notice that someText has changed so I can, for example, set needsDisplay to true for the view and do some other work.

How an I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you need KVC for this? KVC works fine in Swift, but there’s an easier way:

```
var SomeText: NSString {
    didSet {
        // do some work every time SomeText is set
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no KVC mechanism for this because this isn't what KVC is for.

In Objective-C, you would implement the setter explicitly (or override if the property is originally from a superclass) and do your work there.

In Swift, the proper approach is the `didSet` mechanism.

`didChangeValueForKey()` is not part of KVC, it's part of KVO (Key-Value Observing). It is not intended to be overridden. It's intended to be called when one is implementing manual change notification (as a pair with `willChangeValueForKey()`).

More importantly, though, there's no reason to believe that it will be called at all for a property which is not being observed by anything. KVO swizzles the class in order to hook into the setters and other mutating accessors *for those properties which are actually being observed*. When such a property is changed (and supports automatic change notification), KVO calls `willChangeValueForKey()` and `didChangeValueForKey()` automatically. But for non-observed properties, those methods are not called.

Finally, in some cases, such as the indexed collection mutation accessors, KVO will use different change notification methods, such as `willChange(_:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:)` and `didChange(_:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:)`.

If you really don't want to use `didSet` for some reason, you would use KVO to observe `self` for changes in the `someText` property and handle changes in `observeValueForKeyPath(_:ofObject:change:context:)`. But this is a bad, clumsy, error-prone, inefficient way of doing a simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

KVO and `didSet` are not mutually exclusive:

```
import Foundation
class C: NSObject {
    dynamic var someText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print("changed to \(someText)")
        }
    }
}

let c = C()
c.someText = "hi"  // prints "changed to hi"

class Observer: NSObject {
    init(_ c: C) {
        super.init()
        c.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "someText", options: [], context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        print("observed change to \(object!.valueForKeyPath(keyPath!))")
    }
}

let o = Observer(c)
c.someText = "test"  // prints "changed to test" and "observed change to test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to [Jaanus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49951/jaanus)'s answer that to make the property KVC compliant, you should declare it as `dynamic var someText: NSString`.

But if you don't need all the bells and whistles oh KVC, `didSet` is the way to go.

**Update**

As for `didChangeValueForKey:` – it is intended for the opposite, for you to notify value for key has changed (if it is not due to one of the cases covered by Foundation). You should use `addObserver(_:forKeyPath:options:context:)` and override `observeValueForKeyPath(_:ofObject:change:context:)` to be notified of changes.

Alternatively you can use one of many 3rd party solutions such as [ReactiveCococa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) or Facebook's [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController)

Comment: Even if I add the dynamic parameter to someText, the didChangeValueForKey method isn't being called. If didChangeValueForKey isn't the right way to know that the value of someText has changed, what is?

Comment: sorry didn't notice that part, it is not the right method indeed, please see my edits